# Writing a book for both print and HTML which can include code samples

Tags: html, tags, publishing

I want to write a book on programming. I need to target both print and HTML.

In order not to get burned with the code examples, I need to be able to include parts of source code which have been marked up with start and end points to ensure the code is up to date and compiles. Extract the code from external files if you will.

I would like some simple format such as Txt2tags rather than latex since I then can use word's fine spelling capabilities.

Any experiences you want to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it has been reported as a missing feature on the text2tag homepage...

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that by starting with [Txt2Tags](http://txt2tags.org/) you will be able to export your documents into [LaTex](http://www.latex-project.org/). To my knowledge this is a one-way street, so by starting with Txt2tags you can still have the flexibility of LaTex, but by going with LaTex you don't get the benefits of Txt2tags.

Comment: Thanks, but my main concern is the inclusion of parts of my external source code. How will txt2tag assist me here?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't dismiss LaTeX too rapidly.  Although it can be a bit of a pain to spellcheck, it's still quite doable with tools like [aspell](http://aspell.net/).

That being said, I would highly recommend using emacs' [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/).  It will provide you with a nice foldable overview of your book's structure, and is much more readable in plain text than LaTeX.  Additionally, since it uses emacs' native syntax highlighting when you export (to HTML, LaTeX, PDF, etc) you'll be able to write the code inline (between #+begin_src tags) and get a much more precise WYSIWYG view of the code snippets you include.

Since emacs will work with aspell out-of-the-box, you'll still be able to check spelling as you work.  Also, it uses LaTeX as an export format, which means you can obtain the same professional/technical look that LaTeX affords.

Comment: I've used LaTeX for many years, writing macros to CTAN etc. I do not wish to travel down that road again. I much prefer words spelling, thesaurus etc.